# Will I get sawwab for answering here

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, ibadah

Salam to all. What I want to ask is a question about answering questions on this site. Due to the characteristics of stack exchange sites, the Islam stack exchange also has some characters i.e. reputations, badges etc. When we answer questions on this site we fell in greed of reputations (that's natural for a human. Isn't it?). Indeed, we want to help people in need of Islamic knowledge but the greed of reputation also mixes with this thought! So my question is that will we get sawwab for answering questions? You may be offended with the word "greed" so you may use "competition for reputation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Those who spend their wealth for increase in self-purification,*
>
> ***And have in their minds no favour from anyone for which a reward is expected in return,***
>
> *But only the desire to seek for the Countenance of their Lord Most High;*
>
> *And soon will they attain (complete) satisfaction. - Qur'an 92:18-21*

You decide first. For which one are you helping others? Is it for 1) the rep of this site, this world, you're working hard and helping others (or) 2) the rep of the after life.

Once, you made a decision, stick with it, and try your best to expect **NO** +10s in your notification bar. That isn't real money (reward) anyways.

And this [platform you're using](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16258/294685), is geared towards gamification and generating reputation. And the fun and the **contending** experience is what mostly drives the users to **answer**. Some don't admit, some control themselves, some don't care for the rep but some got used to doing it (just) for the rep.

Hence, it's a test for some and one needs to control himself and if he is so particular about the rep of the after life, then he should not be having fun and not feel **contented** with the +10s.

**Tips**

- Visit the [Questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions) regularly, and try to <strike>answer</strike> *help* the questioners. It can be either by answering, commenting, pointing them to existing rich questions which could be helpful to the questioner etc.
- Offer your <strike>hard earned</strike> bounty on other good questions out there in the site regularly, which you feel haven't received much attention or on some questions which are left out unanswered which you couldn't answer but the questioner is really waiting for the answers. (This is analogous to giving to Zakah out of your real money)

Comment: Azam a great answer as you usually do!! And I am accepting your answer for the reference to ayyah which you have given along...